# Make Date Range Dynamic

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a function I created to make a date range x years from the month I am on. However I have hard coded the values which correct the months which makes it not extendible. I would like to make it so that this script works better without having to use hardcoded "if" statements in my for-loop. Thank you for your help!

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lJGbE

html:

```
<button onclick="dateRange(2)">Create Select Range</button>
```

js:

```
function dateRange(x) {
    var startDay = 1;
    var numYears = x;
    var numMonths = ((numYears * 12) + 1);

    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    month = month + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    var createOptions = []; //array storage for options

    createOptions.push("<option selected='selected'>Select...</option>");

    for (i = 0; i < numMonths; i++) {

        var tempMonth = month + i;
        var tempYear = 0;
        if ((tempMonth > 12) && (tempMonth <= 24)) {
            tempMonth = tempMonth - 12;
            tempYear = 1;
        }
        else if ((tempMonth > 24) && (tempMonth <= 36)) {
            tempMonth = tempMonth - 24;
            tempYear = 2;
        }

        switch (tempMonth) {
            case 1: simpleMonth = "Jan"; break;
            case 2: simpleMonth = "Feb"; break;
            case 3: simpleMonth = "Mar"; break;
            case 4: simpleMonth = "Apr"; break;
            case 5: simpleMonth = "May"; break;
            case 6: simpleMonth = "Jun"; break;
            case 7: simpleMonth = "Jul"; break;
            case 8: simpleMonth = "Aug"; break;
            case 9: simpleMonth = "Sep"; break;
            case 10: simpleMonth = "Oct"; break;
            case 11: simpleMonth = "Nov"; break;
            case 12: simpleMonth = "Dec"; break;
        }

        var makeDate = tempMonth + "/" + startDay + "/" + (year + tempYear);
        var makeSimple = simpleMonth + "-" + (year + tempYear);

        createOptions.push("<option value='" + makeDate + "'>" + makeSimple + "</option>");
    }
    //return (createOptions);
    alert(createOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: (Didn't need to use the index from the for loop and use ++ instead also moved declaration of tempMonth outside the for-loop.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aIlfG

js:

```
function dateRange(x) {
    var startDay = 1;
    var numMonths = ((x * 12) + 1);

    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    month = month + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    var createOptions = []; //array storage for options

    createOptions.push("<option selected='selected'>Select...</option>");

    var tempMonth = month - 1;
    var tempYear = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numMonths; i++) {

        if (tempMonth >= 12) {
            tempMonth = tempMonth - 11;
            tempYear++;
        } else {
            tempMonth++;
        }

        switch (tempMonth) {
            case 1: simpleMonth = "Jan"; break;
            case 2: simpleMonth = "Feb"; break;
            case 3: simpleMonth = "Mar"; break;
            case 4: simpleMonth = "Apr"; break;
            case 5: simpleMonth = "May"; break;
            case 6: simpleMonth = "Jun"; break;
            case 7: simpleMonth = "Jul"; break;
            case 8: simpleMonth = "Aug"; break;
            case 9: simpleMonth = "Sep"; break;
            case 10: simpleMonth = "Oct"; break;
            case 11: simpleMonth = "Nov"; break;
            case 12: simpleMonth = "Dec"; break;
        }

        var makeDate = tempMonth + "/" + startDay + "/" + (year + tempYear);
        var makeSimple = simpleMonth + "-" + (year + tempYear);

        createOptions.push("<option value='" + makeDate + "'>" + makeSimple + "</option>");
    }
    //return (createOptions);
    alert(createOptions);
}
```